# Direct SQL query error: Column not found

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have a table with content:
[image] 
 I want to write a direct SQL query to select the `time_delivery`, where `country` is, for example, `DK` in this case.
 So it should return `1-5`. 
 I was following a tutorial: https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/ 
 And tried modifying query myself like this:

```
$country= "DK";
$query = 'SELECT time_delivery FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE country = '
     .$country . ' LIMIT 1';
```

But I get an error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DK' in 'where clause'` 
 I would assume that it has something to do with the fact the in the tutorial he uses an `int` but I want to use a string

Comment: Use bind queries. That will solve your problem. It will handle all type conversions.

Comment: I think it is because the quotes are wrong, therefore SQL thinks `DK` corresponds to a column rather than a value `"DK"`.

Your full query will look like this: 
`SELECT time_delivery FROM (TABLE) WHERE country = DK LIMIT 1`

You can fix this my quoting the value using the database connector. 
`$db->quote($country)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
$country= "DK";
$query = 'SELECT time_delivery FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE country ="'.$country.'" LIMIT 1';
```

Answer (score 1):

add **"** on **value** because it takes value as a column name.

```
   $country= "DK";
    $query = 'SELECT time_delivery FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE country = "'
         .$country . '" LIMIT 1';
```

Comment: What is mean :-> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '''' in 'where clause' and my where clause is :->  WHERE (`''` = '''') full code : https://justpaste.it/5vz3d @Qaisar Satti